# Login failed condition not working properly

Tags: android

I have an app in which user authentication is done sending a request and if response is successful the app navigated to next activity.If username password is correct it navigates but if it is incorrect the dialog box pops up and does not close and in my logs I get

```
java.io.IOException: HTTP/1.1 401 The username or password you entered is incorrect.
```

I have handled it in my code that if response is not successful display a toast message Login failed and dismiss dialog box.if I enter incorrect credentials it is not showing it.That part of the code is unreachable I checked using breakpoint.

My code:

```
buttonlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if(etemail.getText().toString().equals("") && etpass.getText().toString().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Enter your username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Logging in..Please wait");
                    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                    progressDialog.show();
                    new Thread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),etemail.getText().toString(),etpass.getText().toString());
                                restApi.setApplicationName("BMC-AndroidforRally");
                                qtestset = new QueryRequest("Users");
                                qtestset.setLimit(1);
                                response=restApi.query(qtestset);
                                if(!response.wasSuccessful())
                                {
                                    parent.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run()
                                        {
                                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Failed..incorrect Username/Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successful.....Logged in as :"+etemail.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    Intent mainintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstPage.class);
                                    mainintent.putExtra("username",etemail.getText().toString());
                                    mainintent.putExtra("password",etpass.getText().toString());
                                    startActivity(mainintent);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e)
                            {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                            }

                        }
                    }).start();

                }

            }
        });
```

Also i have created a new thread for faster execution.

Answer (score 0):

In this concepts no need to implement runnable thread.
  Remove Thread in OnClickListener it will work correctly.Because of thread only its showing old message(still that running). Best remove thread in OnClickListener or stop thread when  condition going to false statement.

Comment: I can't see the progress dialog and also the toast is not shown